# How to combine two jquery function/events

Tags: jquery

How to combine two jQuery function/events? For example, something like:

```
$(window).load(function()  &  $( window ).resize(function() {
//Code for action
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for multiple event binding on a same element

The first parameter `events`:

> An object in which the string keys represent one or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, and the values represent a handler function to be called for the event(s).

```
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    // Common event handler here
});
```

You can also use named function

```
function handler() {
    // Common event handler here
}

$(window).load(handler);
$(window).resize(handler);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have single handler for both :

```
$(window).on('load resize',function() {
  //Code for action
});
```

If both have different handler then use:

```
$("window").on({
load : function() {
    // Handle load
},
resize: function() {
    // Handle resize
});
```